# How do I find the number of bytes worth of silence to use for a certain amount of time?

Tags: audio

Sorry if this question has been asked before but I did not find any matching what I'm looking for. I have a certain amount of time that I want for an audio file to be silent, so I can put that into some pcm data. But I've no idea how times I need to add b'\x00\x00' for it to equal a certain amount of time. I have this line of code:

```
pcm += struct.pack('<h', 0)*some_number
```

so how would I calculate "some_number" based on a certain amount of time?
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: What's the sample format, channel count, and sample rate?

Comment: 2 channels, 48000 sample rate, and 16-bit sample format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

16-bits means 2 bytes per PCM value. Stereo means two channels (two PCM values per frame). So that totals 4 bytes per frame. 48000 fps is frames per second, so multiply the number of seconds by 4.